# Switching Azure website mode from FREE to SHARED fails

Tags: asp.net, windows, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have a BizSparks subscription to Windows Azure, I have created a website and deployed my MVC 4 app. All went well, the site running under : http://rfi-uat.azurewebsites.net/

Now, I am trying to set the CName and point my domain name to the site. I read and understood that in order to do this, I need to change the site mode from FREE to Shared. However, every time I try it says

> Mode change could not be saved

The detail of the message reads

> Please try again. If the problem persists, contact support.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This really sounds like a billing support issue, where you'd need to open a ticket (and billing support should be included with your subscription).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared to be an issue for certain websites. In particular websites in `East Asia` region. I first lodged a ticket to the `billing support` as advised by @David M. above. The Win Azure team responded:

> Your question appears to require technical support for 
>   instead of billing and subscription support for Azure as selected.

Then I kept trying differnt things, and I found that few other operations fail occasionally on that particular website (which is the only one in `East Asia` region in my account). 
I created a new Azure website in East US region and everything went smooth from there on.